# Char** struct member Invalid Write

Tags: arrays, c, string, valgrind

I have the following struct

```
typedef struct mystr{
  char** str;
}*mystr;
```

a definition in main

```
mystr mst = NULL;
init(&mst);
```

that I want to initialize in this function as such

```
void init(mystr* m){
  *m = malloc(sizeof(mystr*));
  (*m)->str = malloc(sizeof(char*)*2);  /*dynamic array of strings with 2 indexes */
}
```

However the last line of the function code causes a valgrind error of invalid write and address 0 bytes after a block has been allocated. Any help?

Comment: you likely missed another layer of allocation.  Did you mean to init each char* with a malloc'd block?

Comment: Don't typedef pointers. It just makes the code harder to understand. And that is likely a large contributor to why this code ends up wrong.

Comment: @Abel That would be the next step, however not even the array allocation works so I have not proceeded to alloc every index.

Comment: `typedef struct mystr *mystr;` is probably a mistake. So is `sizeof(mystr*)`

Comment: Try rewriting your code using something like "typedef struct S_MyStruct { char** str; } MyStr, * P_MyStr;". This makes it clear which is the struct name, the typedef for the struct name and the typedef for a pointer to the struct.

Answer (score 0):

if you define it like that

```
typedef struct mystr{
  char **str;
}mystr;
```

`malloc()` returns a pointer and if you `init()` you have to remember that C copies the value of the argument to the stack.

```
void init( mystr ** _mystr )
{
  *_mystr = malloc( sizeof(mystr));
  (*_mystr)->str = malloc( sizeof(char*) * 2 );
}
```

and you use it like

```
mystr *mystr;

init( &mystr );
```

another version which avoids double pointers is

```
mystr *initMystr()
{ 
  mystr *_mystr = malloc( sizeof(mystr));
  _mystr->str = malloc( sizeof(char*) * 2 );
  
  return _mystr;
}
```

and

```
mystr *mystr = initMystr();
```